# Elixir best data structure for testing comparison

Tags: testing, elixir

I have two array outputs where I need to iterate over each struct, and compare the counts where the source's match. The comparison needs to be less than or equal to. My output sources look like this:

```
output_1: [%{source: "facebook", count: 3}, %{count: 1, source: "linkedin"}]

output_2: [%{source: "facebook", count: 2}, %{count: 1, source: "linkedin"}]
```

Whats the best data structure to implement in order to make the Enumerables easiest and most efficient to compare?

Comment: Will you always have the same sources in both lists? Or is it possible that `output_1` will have a source that is not in `output_2`?

Comment: Yes, they'll always match on either side.

Comment: You don't have any structs in your question--those are maps.

Answer (score 1):

If your order isn't guaranteed, my preferred way is to turn the reference list into a map and compare things by source.

```rb
iex> output_1 = [%{source: "facebook", count: 3}, %{count: 1, source: "linkedin"}]
[%{count: 3, source: "facebook"}, %{count: 1, source: "linkedin"}]
iex> output_2 = [%{source: "facebook", count: 2}, %{count: 1, source: "linkedin"}]
[%{count: 2, source: "facebook"}, %{count: 1, source: "linkedin"}]
iex> limits = Map.new(output_1, &{&1.source, &1.count})
%{"facebook" => 3, "linkedin" => 1}
iex> Enum.all?(output_2, & &1.count <= limits[&1.source])
true
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current output format should be very efficient with the following code.  You didn't say what you expected your output to be, nor in which direction the comparison should be done: `output2 <= output1` or `output1 <= output2`, so I'm assuming a list of booleans and `output1 <= output2`:

```
defmodule A do

  def compare([%{count: count1}|maps1], [%{count: count2}|maps2]) do
    [count1 <= count2 | compare(maps1, maps2) ]
  end
  def compare([], []), do: []

end
```

The following does the same thing and is easier to come up with and understand:

```
defmodule A do
  def compare(list1, list2), do: _compare(list1, list2, [])

  defp _compare([%{count: count1}|maps1], [%{count: count2}|maps2], acc) do
    _compare(maps1, maps2, [count1 <= count2 | acc])      
  end
  defp _compare([], [], acc) do
    Enum.reverse(acc)
  end

end
```

In iex:

```
~/elixir_programs$ iex a.ex
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Interactive Elixir (1.8.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> out1 = [%{source: "facebook", count: 3}, %{count: 1, source: "linkedin"}]
[
  %{count: 3, source: "facebook"},
  %{count: 1, source: "linkedin"}
]

iex(2)> out2 = [%{source: "facebook", count: 2}, %{count: 1, source: "linkedin"}]
[
  %{count: 2, source: "facebook"},
  %{count: 1, source: "linkedin"}
]

iex(3)> A.compare(out1, out2)                               
[false, true]
```

If instead, you need the result to be a single boolean, i.e. the facebook count is less than or equal to AND the linkedin count is less than or equal to, you can change the *accumulator*:

```
defmodule A do
  def compare(list1, list2), do: _compare(list1, list2, true)

  defp _compare([%{count: count1}|maps1], [%{count: count2}|maps2], true) do
    _compare(maps1, maps2, count1 <= count2)

  end
  defp _compare(_, _, false), do: false  #If you find a false comparison, stop and return false
  defp _compare([], [], _), do: true

end
```

In iex:

```
iex(22)> c "a.ex"
warning: redefining module A (current version defined in memory)
  a.ex:1
[A]

iex(23)> A.compare(out1, out2)
false
```

This also works:

```
defmodule A do
  def compare(list1, list2) do
    List.first(list1)[:count] <= List.first(list2)[:count]
    and
    List.last(list1)[:count] <= List.last(list2)[:count]
  end
end
```

> Whats the best data structure to implement in order to make the Enumerables easiest and most efficient to compare?

Otherwise, I would nominate a [keyword list](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/keywords-and-maps.html) like this:

```
[facebook: 3, linkedin: 1]
[facebook: 2, linkedin: 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would probably to be use [`Enum.zip/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#zip/2) with [`Enum.all?/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#all?/2). Something like the following should work

```
output_1 = Enum.sort(output_1, fn a, b -> a.source <= b.source end)
output_2 = Enum.sort(output_2, fn a, b -> a.source <= b.source end)

output_1
|> Enum.zip(output_2)
|> Enum.all?(fn a, b -> a.count == b.count end)
```